# Why do TeX list items use two backslashes?

Tags: macros, lists, tex-core

In TeX packages one finds definitions of lists as:

```
\def\l{\\\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma}
```

The one backslash is understandable, it represent the active character for the macro i.e, \gamma, but what do the other two do, why are they there?

Comment: Can you point out which packages define these? Normally `\\` maps to new line and to `\cr` in `\halign` based environments. So, depending on the context, it could mean different things.

Comment: I have been reading http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.102.2532 and trying to understand the example on sorting a list!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\\` is just an arbitrary (short) control sequence. It allows you to do something with the list just by defining it as a one-parameter macro:

```
\begingroup
\def\\#1{\typeout{\string#1}}
\l  % prints out the tokens in the list
\endgroup
```

However, I think `\\` is a bad choice because it has a meaning in TeX/LaTeX. LaTeX generally uses `\do` for this purpose, and packages such as `expl3` use a special hidden separator so that you can add `\\` or `\do` as normal list elements.

Comment: \\ has no meaning in plain TeX. One of the questions in the TeXbook asks why the author (meaning Knuth) didn't give it a meaning. The answer is that it is just too convenient for other uses. Personally, I find `\\\foo\\\bar` harder to read. I think something like `\do\foo\do\bar` is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a list of control sequences, you don't need the extra `\\` — you can use token lists and "pop" off the first item.  Eijkhout's *TeX by Topic* gives some code that does that in his chapter on token lists.

If you want more general contents in the list, you need a separator.  The `\\` is what Knuth used as a separator in Appendix D of *The TeXbook*, so I guess that is the convention, but you could use an active character like `~` as a separator.